# Solving LP problem with dependant equality constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Maximize}&\enspace 1.04x_4 + 1.09x_9 + 1.15x_{11}\\
\text{subject to}&\enspace x_1+x_6=5000\\
&x_2+x_7+x_{10}=1.04x_1\\
&x_3+x_8+x_{11}=1.04x_2+1.09x_6\\
&x_4+x_9=1.04x_3+1.09x_7\\
&x_5=1.04x_4+1.09x_8+1.15x_{10}\\
&x_1,\dots,x_{11}\geq 0
\end{align}
$$
My approach to solving this problem is to transform each equality into an inequality, e.g. the first constraint is equivalent to 
$$x_1+x_6\leq5000$$
$$-x_1-x_6\leq5000$$
I would then do this for the rest. However, the other constraints have variables on the the right hand side of the "$=$", does this mean I must subtract them, making those constraints less than or equal to zero?

Also, if I were to do this, I would only have $10$ constraints but there is $11$ variables. Isn't this a problem?

Comment: You have 21 constraints (of which 11 are nonnegativity constraints). For the simplex method your proposed method will work.

Comment: @LinAlg How did you get 21?

Comment: 10 regular constraints and 11 nonnegativity constraints